# Linq select with filtering not working

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to select one field last record in filtered database (this is different than last inserted record). I tried with following code in controller but instead of field value, i'm getting "true" or "false", depending on if there's results after filtering or not.

```
List<Pozicije> poz = new List<Pozicije>();
poz = db.Pozicijes.Where(p => p.grupa == grupa)
                    .OrderBy(p => p.sifra_pozicije).ToList();
string pos = poz.Select(p => p.sifra_pozicije.Contains(s)).LastOrDefault().ToString();
```

can someone point me how to get value i need instead?

Comment: Change the `Select` to `Where`

Comment: Do you really know what `LastOrDefault` returns? Why are you using it instead of `Last`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead. I've combined both parts of your query into one.

```
 var pos =
     Convert.ToString(db.Pozicijes.Where(p => p.grupa == grupa
                                              && p.sifra_pozicije.Contains(s))
                                  .OrderByDescending(p => p.sifra_pozicije)
                                  .Select(p => p.sifra_pozicije)
                                  .FirstOrDefault());
```

If it doesn't work, you may need to tell us what types `s` and `sifra_pozicije` are.

Answer (score 1):

`LastOrDefault` is not supported with LINQ to Entities/LINQ TO SQL. You need to do `OrderByDescending` and then get `First` record. Like:

```
string pos = db.Pozicijes.Where(p => p.grupa == grupa &&  p.sifra_pozicije.Contains(s)))
            .OrderByDescending(p=> p.sifra_pozicije)
            .Select(r=> r.sifra_pozicije)
            .First();
```